# Successful Retrofit 2 Communication to the server but body is null

Tags: rest, retrofit, retrofit2, okhttp

I can communicate with Server through retrofit2 and okhttp3 libraries and I get following

```
D/LT: Response successful. 

Code: 200 
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 441
Date: Tue, 14 Jun 2016 08:01:23 GMT

D/LT: responseBody = null
```

As you can see, I get a successful response and it is 441 Chars long.

**So, why am I getting a null body?**

These are my sources

```
    MyService client        = MyServiceGenerator.createService(MyService.class);

    String contentType      = "application/json";

    String bodyContent      = "{'userId': 'user', 'password': 'pwd', 'deviceId': '123', 'applicationId': '123'}";

    RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), bodyContent);

    Call call               = client.session(contentType, requestBody);

    // Asynchronic way
    call.enqueue(new Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) {
            Log.d("LT","Reached!");
            if ( response.isSuccessful() ) {
                Log.d("LT", "Response successful. Code: "+ response.code() + " " + response.headers());

                Void decodedResponseBody = (Void)response.body();

                if ( decodedResponseBody != null )
                    Log.d("LT", "decodedResponseBody :"+decodedResponseBody);
                else
                    Log.d("LT", "responseBody = null");

            } else {
                try {

                    Log.d("LT", "response not successful: error: (" + response.errorBody().string()+") message: ("+response.message()+")");

                    if ( response != null ) {
                        Log.d("LT", "response != null ");
                        String decodedResponseBody = response.body().toString();
                        Log.d("LT", "Response Body: "+ decodedResponseBody+" raw: "+response.raw() + " headers: " + response.headers());
                    } else {
                        Log.d("LT", "response == null");
                    }


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call call, Throwable t) {
            //Handle failure
            Log.d("LT", t.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

My Service Interface

```
public interface MyService {

@POST("sessions")
Call<Void> session(@Header("Content-Type") String contentType, @Body RequestBody body);
}
```

MyServiceGenerator

```
public class MyServiceGenerator {

    public static final String API_BASE_URL                = "http://...";

    // Here we add an interceptor in order to be able to listen the most typical messages
    private static LoggingInterceptor myLoggingInterceptor = new LoggingInterceptor();
    private static OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient         = new OkHttpClient.Builder();//.addInterceptor(myLoggingInterceptor);

    private static Retrofit.Builder builder                = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(API_BASE_URL).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

    public static <S> S createService(Class<S> serviceClass) {
        Retrofit retrofit = builder.client(httpClient.build()).build();
        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }


 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it!

I just needed to serialize as a ResponseBody Object.

```
D/LT: decodedResponseBody :okhttp3.ResponseBody$1@517fd33 decodedResponseBody.content-type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8 string: {"userId":"user","deviceId":"123","applicationId":"123","sessionToken":"DE57FDACCFD199EE9B96ADD4D6B1E30DC8B231D0DDC3B84EEEE04C68F9993210","companies":[{"name":"Bauernhof","id":"4C10E349D79149BACCFEE7C35E71EDAF11A9895215BA03BAED4746EAC7CB1E29"},{"name":"Farm","id":"280EBAB2615378E1433F7C57140E1643575C32F99C173779759947B6E8732BB6"},{"name":"Schweinfurt","id":"C5CD9569869CC93B7D89BBE7AABEF9D158AB1D9BEB79D3C317D8FA492C903EAB"}]}
```

These are now my **modified** sources

```
    MyService client        = MyServiceGenerator.createService(MyService.class);

    String contentType      = "application/json";

    String bodyContent      = "{'userId': 'user', 'password': 'pwd', 'deviceId': '123', 'applicationId': '123'}";

    RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), bodyContent);

    Call<ResponseBody> call = client.session(contentType, requestBody);

    // Asynchronic way
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
            Log.d("LT","Reached!");
            if ( response.isSuccessful() ) {
                Log.d("LT", "Response successful. Code: "+ response.code() + " " + response.headers());

                ResponseBody decodedResponseBody = response.body();

                if ( decodedResponseBody != null )
                    try {
                        Log.d("LT", "decodedResponseBody :"+decodedResponseBody+" decodedResponseBody.content-type: "+decodedResponseBody.contentType()+" string: "+decodedResponseBody.string());
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                else
                    Log.d("LT", "responseBody == null");

            } else {
                try {

                    Log.d("LT", "response not successful: error: (" + response.errorBody().string()+") message: ("+response.message()+")");

                    if ( response != null ) {
                        Log.d("LT", "response != null ");
                        ResponseBody decodedResponseBody = response.body().toString();
                        Log.d("LT", "Response Body: "+ decodedResponseBody+" raw: "+response.raw() + " headers: " + response.headers());
                    } else {
                        Log.d("LT", "response == null");
                    }


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
            //Handle failure
            Log.d("LT", t.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

My Service Interface

```
public interface MyService {

@POST("sessions")
Call<ResponseBody> session(@Header("Content-Type") String contentType, @Body RequestBody body);
}
```